# Why is the == operator not yielding the same result as strcmp?

Tags: c++, string, equality, implicit-conversion, c-strings

I've created a two dimensional array of character pointers. I'd like to use it to create a dictionary whereby, if the variable ent is part of the dictionary, the corresponding dictionary entry for that word is retrieved if it exists. I'm currently using strcmp, but only because the == operator is giving me a hard time. I'm not sure why the == operator is not leading to the desired results.

I suspect it might have something to do with pointer comparison, as I'm comparing a pointer to a string with another pointer to a string, and not necessarily its contents.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char *dictionary[][2] {
        {"First","Monday"},
        {"Second","Tuesday"},
        {"Third","Wednesday"},
        {"Fourth","Thursday"},
        {"Fifth","Friday"},
        {"Sixth","Saturday"},
        {"Seventh","Sunday"},
        {"",""}
    };

    char ent[80] = "Sixth";

        for (int i{}; *dictionary[i][0]; i++) {
            if (!strcmp(dictionary[i][0], ent)) { 
                std::cout << "Word found: " << ent 
                          << " corresponds to: " << dictionary[i][1] 
                          << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }

    std::cout << ent << " not found." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

I would like to replace   `if (!strcmp(dictionary[i][0], word))` with something like 
`if (word == dictionary[i][0])` and have it yield `Word found: Sixth corresponds to Saturday`

If I cannot do this with the == operator, is there a way to do this through a function that uses pointers but doesn't rely on a header?

Thanks!

Comment: Because with operator == you compare equality of the pointers themselves

Comment: You can use `==` if you switch to use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Assuming you are trying to compare arrays of char, `==` compares pointers (the address of the first character), which is not what `strcmp()` does.   Instead of using pointers and arrays, consider making use of `std::string` - which does have a comparison operator that works as you expect.

Comment: If you would like to use C++ code where `==` works as you expect, then you really need to write C++ code that uses C++ classes, like `std::string`s, instead of writing C code that uses plain `char` pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the condition of the if statement

```
if (word == dictionary[i][0])
```

there are compared addresses of first characters of the strings.

In expressions arrays with rare exceptions as for example using them in the sizeof operator are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

For example if you will write such an if-statement like this

```
if ( "hello" == "hello" ) { /*...*/ }
```

then the expression evaluates either to `true` or `false` depending on the compiler option that specifies whether equal string literals are stored internally as one string or as separate strings.

You could define the dictionary such a way that the type of elements of which would be `std::string`. In this case you can use the equality operator ==.

In this case you can compare an object of the type `std::string` with character arrays containing strings because the character arrays would be implicitly converted to temporary objects of the type `std::string`.

Comment: You guys are really quick. Thanks! That was what I suspected.